# Arbitrary date / day math with Python

Tags: python, date, time

I'm looking at doing some basic day / date time math with Python, but ideally this shouldn't be tied to any particular date.

Typically the answer would be "use the datetime" library, however *as far as I'm aware* it can't do what I require.

The requirement is pretty simple, be able to do something like "Monday 15:00 - 24 hours" and return "Sunday 15:00", or "Friday 01:00 - 3 days 4 hours" and return "Monday 21:00".

Again doesn't matter *which* Monday or any concept of dates at all, limiting it to a maximum of a week forwards or backwards is enough for the purpose of the program.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Cheers

Comment: Can't you just pick an arbitray monday in the middle of a month and use `datetime.datetime`, if you can limit to a week?

Comment: E.g. `dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 12, 15) # a monday at 15 hours` then simply `(dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)).strftime("%A %X")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure you are sticking to a week, you could get away with simply picking an arbitrary week in a month and use that with `datetime.datetime`:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 12, 15) # a monday at 15 hours
>>> (dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)).strftime("%A %X")
'Sunday 15:00:00'
```

Now, for Friday:

```
>>> dt2 = dt.replace(day=dt.day+4, hour=1) # Friday 01.00 hours
>>> (dt2 - datetime.timedelta(days=3, hours=4)).strftime("%A %X")
'Monday 21:00:00'
```

Just for fun, a basic implementation:

```
_fullnames = ('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday',
              'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday')
_abrevnames = 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'
_day_nums = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

DAY_MAP = {**dict(zip(_fullnames, _day_nums)),
           **dict(zip(_abrevnames, _day_nums))}


class WeekDay:

    def __init__(self, day, hour):
        self.day = day
        self.hour = hour

    @property
    def day(self):
        return self._day

    @day.setter
    def day(self, day):
        if isinstance(day, int):
            if 0 <= day <= 6:
                self._day = day
            else:
                raise ValueError("Day must be 0 <= day <= 6")
        elif isinstance(day, str):
            try:
                self._day = DAY_MAP[day.lower()]
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError("trying to set day"
                                 "with unrecognized string"
                                 f"{day}")
        else:
            raise ValueError("day must be string or int")

    @property
    def hour(self):
        return self._hour

    @hour.setter
    def hour(self, hour):
        if 0 <= hour <= 23:
            self._hour = hour
        else:
            raise ValueError("Hour must be: 0 <= hour <= 23")

    def delta(self, days=0, hours=0):
        assert isinstance(days, int) and isinstance(hours, int)
        h_delta = (self.hour + hours)
        hour, extraday = h_delta % 24, h_delta // 24
        day = (self.day + days + extraday) % 7
        return WeekDay(day, hour)

    def __str__(self):
        d = _fullnames[self.day].capitalize()
        return f"{d} {self.hour:02}:00"

    def __repr__(self):
        klass = type(self).__name__
        return f"{klass}({self.day},{self.hour})"
```

In action:

```
In [31]: wd = WeekDay('Monday', 15)

In [32]: print(wd.delta(hours=-24))
Sunday 15:00

In [33]: wd2 = WeekDay('Fri',1)

In [34]: print(wd2.delta(days=-3, hours=-3))
Monday 22:00

In [35]: print(wd2.delta(days=-3, hours=-4))
Monday 21:00
```

Note, the `delta` method is a bit janky in that it requires the caller to specify *negative* or *positive* hours/days consistently. Perhaps a *better approach* would be to follow the model of `datetime` and define a `WeekDayDelta` object that takes only positive integers, and then implement `__sub__` and `__add__` to accept `WeekDayDelta` objects, and handle the signs in those methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got you right but I think all you care about is weekdays calculations, you don't care about the particular date.
in that case you could make the calculations to a particular date and the just print the weekday and time hence:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse('monday 15:00').strftime("%A %X")
```